# Docusign: How can I find the recipient signing url using C#

Tags: docusignapi

When Docusign send email to recipients to signing document. In the mail body contains a review document URL

URL: https://demo.docusign.net/signing/emails/v2-bf5d67db0fef4c3cb55bcfff9b1185fa69c97254c6ea456c97965e769e9e9789a8d1cebdb16445a6afa077c9834ab242

How can I generate this link using C# code?

Actually I will send a custom email from our system with this url.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate the DocuSign email link for security reasons. Imagine as a developer you generate that link, then you can send it to anyone to sign, rendering email authentication useless and DocuSign cannot prove who signed. DocuSign helps ensure your documents are legally binding.

However, if custom email is a must, then here's your option:

- Use DocuSign "branding" feature for some basic customization around colors
- You as the developer can take up the responsibility of authentication. You can do this by using the "embedded" flow. So if a legal case comes it's up to you to demonstrate user validity. Documentation is here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding. The specific line for generating a URL (which is different type of url than email links) is this API call (there's an equivalent C# function):

  POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient

The flow you would do here is: you build email however you want -> customer clicks link in email -> redirects to your webpage -> you handle auth -> redirect user to the generated link -> customer signs

In the flow described here, DocuSign will have audit logs on which link is used so just beware you will need to do the auth work if you want it legally binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `EnvelopesApi` to create and send envelopes to recepeients, you can do something like this:

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
EnvelopeDefinition env = MakeEnvelope(YOUR_PARAMETERS);

var summary = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(_context.AccountId, env);
```

The `EnvelopeSummary` object has a property called `RecipientSigningUri`. You can use `summary.RecipientSigningUri`  in your email.